SSO between next js application and and asp.net framework
Hi have an application built using next.js and ASP.NET core WEB API called as C1 and i have one more application built on asp.net framework using MVC called as H1. I want to create a SSO like experience as user should login to C1 application then when someone opens my H1 then i should not ask for authentication.
One way i was thinking to have a secret key stored in both and create a JWT and send it to H1 from C1, is there any other way to do that

as alternative or othwr way you coudl try using the OAuth 2.0/OpenID Connect approach whcih provides a robust and flexible SSO solution that supports modern security standards and integration needs. While the initial setup may require more effort, the long-term benefits in terms of security, scalability, and interoperability make it a worthwhile investment for most applications. However, if you need a simpler or more controlled setup for a smaller application, the JWT-based approach might be sufficient. at the end decision could made based your requirement and project structure
